# mach_vm_write failing with (os/kern) invalid address

Tags: c, macos, kernel

I've created some code to write memory to another process on the system, but mach_vm_write() fails with the "(os/kern) invalid address" error, despite the address seemingly being valid. My code is below.

```
if ((kret = task_for_pid(mach_task_self(), pid, &task)) == KERN_SUCCESS)
    {
        //this succeeds with the correct value.
        if ((kret = get_task_base(task, &base)) == KERN_SUCCESS)
        {
            char patch_1[6] = {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};
            mach_vm_address_t address_1 = base + 0x77777;

            //this also succeeds
            if ((kret = mach_vm_protect(task, address_1, 6, TRUE, VM_PROT_READ | VM_PROT_WRITE | VM_PROT_EXECUTE)) == KERN_SUCCESS)
            {
                //fails with "(os/kern) invalid address" despite using the same value as the previous mach_vm_protect() call.
                if ((kret = mach_vm_write(task, address_1, (vm_offset_t)&patch_1, 6)) == KERN_SUCCESS)
                {

                }
                else printf("mach_vm_write failed w/ error %d: %s\n", kret, mach_error_string(kret));
            }
            else printf("mach_vm_protect failed w/ error %d: %s\n", kret, mach_error_string(kret));
        }
        else printf("mach_vm_region_recurse failed w/ error %d: %s\n", kret, mach_error_string(kret));
    }
else printf("task_for_pid failed w/ error %d: %s\n", kret, mach_error_string(kret));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the reason mach_vm_write() was failing was that my mach_vm_protect() call was setting the maximum protection.
The call should have looked like this:

```
mach_vm_protect(task, address_1, 6, FALSE, VM_PROT_READ | VM_PROT_WRITE | VM_PROT_EXECUTE)
```